# Download samlpe from streaming source (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I am trying to create a program that will listen to a sound stream and tell me which song is playing using `Sony's` API.

The stream that I'm trying to look at is: [The Stream](http://ads-e-bauerse-fm-05-gos2.sharp-stream.com/popfm_dk_mp3)

However, i haven't done this type of thing before so my question is how would I collect a small sample (10 - 15 sec) from a sound stream.

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: @UlugToprak i have updated the link

Comment: take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/daniel-j/5044334) program listens to spotify stream. not familiar with `sony's` API are you trying to listen from the microphone or just from the sound streams?

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this https://github.com/noamtcohen/AudioStreamer

Comment: @SatishPatel this streams from my microphone. What i am looking for is more a "Robot" process that runs and gets a sample.